# why dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: method can't dealloc view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use `dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion:` method to dismiss view controller. But the view controller's `-(void) dealloc{}` method wasn't called. And finally, I received a memory warning and the app crashed. I don't know why and how to solve it.

Comment: You can use Instruments to profile the app. Hit "Profile" to start it and choose the memory leaks tool. It will tell you why you're getting memory warnings.

Comment: @Fogmeister I tried.And no memory leak.

Comment: It will also show allocations. You could also add an exception breakpoint to catch it. Also, any code you can provide will help. Where in your app are you using up the memory?

Comment: @Fogmeister The allocation is about 1.4 MB,but I got 6 memory.This confused me.

Comment: Yeah, code or something will help. Or a crash log, or an exception breakpoint.

Comment: I guess there exists retain cycle. SO check while presenting the view the dealloc of the presenting ViewController is getting called or not. If it is not getting called then see what is actually retaining the presenting ViewController. According to apple doc the ViewController which is presenting the view have responsibility to dismiss the ViewController. If that is the case then present and dismiss the ViewController using custom delegate method.

Comment: @Gyanendra I bet you're right. Do you have a delegate property on the modal ViewController that you're dismissing?

Comment: we don't have default delegate property. But we can create like this.Suppose ViewController1 is presenting ViewController2 then in ViewController1 we can have a method-(void)dismisViewController1{[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];} then in ViewController1 we will have a property @property(nonatomic, weak)ViewController2 *view2; similarly in ViewController2 have a property @property(nonatomic, weak)ViewController1 *view1; synthesise both the property.In ViewController1 viewDidLoad write -(void)viewDidLoad{view2.view1 = self;}.

Comment: Then while dismissing ViewController2 simply dismiss ViewController1 also by calling [view1 dismisViewController1] that way we can do. Just try this and check whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem.It's because ARC can't release NSTimer automatically.

Comment: This solved my problem! Make sure you call `[timer invalidate]` and `timer = nil` to ensure the view controller is released.